# Corrupted Disk & Initramfs booting

Tags: initramfs, lubuntu

I was using my Lubuntu PC when someone came and shut it down pressing the power button. When I started it again it started to show the initramfs booting (every time that I start it).

I use `fsck` when I want to use it but I would like to know if there is any way to fix this issue permanently.

Comment: I would've thought fsck would fix the issue if the issue is with a filesystem that needed fixing

Answer (score -1):

In `/etc/default/grub` change `delay` to `0`
It keeps the menu from appearing. Initramfs is always going to start the computer. You can't do away with it. But you can display less messages regarding it.

Comment: Could you possibly diagnose the issue and modify your answer to include how setting a zero delay for Grub would resolve it?